# Upload de arquivo remoto com Javascript

Tags: javascript, post

É possível fazer uma requisição `POST` enviando um arquivo como parâmetro?

Por exemplo o site do [TinyPic](http://tinypic.com/) contém um campo do tipo `file`, e quero enviar uma imagem direto da minha aplicação para o TinyPic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, é possível fazer requisições POST por JavaScript usando [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Usando_XMLHttpRequest), vulgo AJAX.

No entanto, não é possível enviar uma imagem para o TinyPic dessa forma, porque isso caracteriza Cross-Site Scripting (XSS): você está tentando postar um formulário de um domínio A (seu site) para um domínio B (tinypic). Isso só poderia rolar se o TinyPic incluísse o seu domínio no cabeçalho [X-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Existe a possibilidade de upar imagens pro TinyPic a partir do seu site pelo [plugin do serviço](http://tinypic.com/developer.php). Eles colocam um iframe na sua página, aí dá certo, porque dentro do iframe há uma página com o domínio `tinypic.com`.

Comment: Obrigado, esclareceu minha dúvida! @rodorgas